# Making it so a .NET Core web app can reference an EF DbContext through an interface rather than directly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a scenario where in the StartUp.cs I need to setup EF with a DbContext like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<TestProjDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

However, my solution is split out into multiple layers.. For example: Api, Data, Domain, Services...

I am trying to make it so the Api project only references the Domain and Services projects. However, DbContext is messing me all up. TestProjDbContext sits within the Data project along with my repositories, migrations, unit of work class, etc..

In my Domain project I have a bunch of interfaces such as IUnitOfWork, ICustomerRepository, etc.. I also created an ITestProjDbContext interface in this project thinking I would somehow be able to pass it into the services.AddDbContext in StartUp.cs. However, this doesn't seem possible.

How can I keep my TestProjDbContext.cs file inside of my Data layer without the Api knowing about the Data layer and only the Domain layer? Or should the DbContext not be in the Data layer and just sit in the Domain layer without using an Interface?

Comment: Why ask essentially the same question in two different ways in two different posts?

Comment: Something to consider...DbContext is essentially an implementation of Unit Of Work and Repository patterns.  You could save yourself a lot of time and code by putting your concrete DbContext into the Domain and ditching all the IRepository interfaces.

Comment: This makes no sense, it's okay for the Project with the Composition Root (WebApi, MVC, Console, WPF application, UWP) to reference all other assemblies and layers. Your **domain** and **services** layer are the one which shouldn't have a reference to **Data** because **Data** is infrastructure (Database, webframework like mvc, web api etc)

Comment: The way to decouple your db access from the domain would be to use repository pattern (for CRUDy usage) or CQRS (for advanced usage where read and writes are to be separated and for a more message oriented approach) and encapsulate the queries within the repository or the command/query handlers (in CQRS). However, with both you lose most of the benefits of the ORM except inside the repository/CQ Handlers

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible provide an interface for your `DbContext` and **inject it** in your **`startup.cs`** and use the interface (ex: `ITestDbContext` ) in your **Api Controllers**.

Here's a walk-through that details this with code examples. I don't want to copy-paste and plagarize it, so I've laid out the steps for you with relevant code w.r.t your situation. Do read the original blog post to get a full understanding of how this works.

### Jerrie Pelser - [Resolve your DbContext as an interface using the ASP.NET 5 dependency injection framework](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/resolve-dbcontext-as-interface-in-aspnet5-ioc-container/)

#### Step 1 - Declare your `ITestDbContext` interface and add your `DbSets`

```
public interface ITestDbContext
{
    DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
    DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    // ....
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

#### Step 2 - Implement the `ITestDbContext` as concrete class `TestDbContext`

```
public class TestDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ITestDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### Step 3 - Setup the Dependency Injection on the Interface in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // Add EF services to the services container.
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    // Register the service and implementation for the database context
    services.AddScoped<ITestDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<TestDbContext>());

  //    ...
}
```

The key line to note is the following

```
services.AddScoped<ITestDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<TestDbContext>());
```

NOTE: Do read up on how the author **Jerrie Pelser** came to use this approach in [his blog post](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/resolve-dbcontext-as-interface-in-aspnet5-ioc-container/).

#### Step 4 - Use the `ITestDbContext` Interface in your Api Controllers

```
public class EpisodesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestDbContext dbContext;

    public EpisodesController(ITestDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work. In order to use `DbSet<T>` or `.Include()` you will still need to reference EF Core assembly. Additionally, since the WebApi Project is the composition root, it must be aware of the Data assembly which contains EF Core (well it could be avoided using complicated dynamic module loading, but it makes no sense, as you need to configure the DbContext in Startup.cs too with the connection string)

Comment: And last but not least, to configure the connection string you also need to reference EF Core (and/or the project with the concrete DbContext implementation) in order to configure it for DI and the connectionstring using `.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>( options => options.UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));`

Comment: @tseng Thank you for the helpful responses. Would you keep the DbContext in the Data layer with the rest of the EF stuff or in the Domain layer with the interfaces and business entities?

Comment: @tseng I know a lot of this is opinionated but can you give me your thoughts on the following: 4 projects - API, Domain, Services, Data. It seems like the API project will need to reference both the Data and Service projects. This way I can inject both repositories and services into my API controllers. Is this correct or should I only be injecting services and make it so only Services know about the Data layer.

Comment: @Tseng `In order to use DbSet<T> or .Include() you will still need to reference EF Core assembly.`  No one's disputing that. OP wanted to using Interface for `DbContext` and my solution does that. Please explain yourself with an answer instead of being vague in the comments.

Comment: The idea behind using an interface on a concrete class is to decouple it, and remove dependencies, i.e. when you have a repository which only returns concrete Models or `IEnumerable<T>`, then you can use this `IRepository<T>` interface in your domain model/business layer w/o referencing the Data Layer (and in this case Database specific, like EFCore and EFCore.SqlServer). But in the case above you just add an interface to it, but still have the dependencies to the database layer and EFCore, so little gain.

Comment: And for UnitTests it has little value either, since mocking DBContext or IQuerybale is rather difficult and that's something which rather leads to integration tests with EF Core InMemory provider (which is what it was made for). But by abstracting EFCore behind CQRS/Repository on other side you'll lose the benefits of using an ORM (i.e. you can't adjust your queries outside of Repository by adding additional filters or projections). It mostly ends up to directly using EF Core in command handlers or repository to abstract it away from the rest, instead of trying to abstract EF itself

Comment: @BlakeRivell: Well it DbContext belongs to Data layer, since it's part of infrastructure and not of your business logic/domain. But your Application still need to be aware of it for. In short: Domain (where Business logic resides) shouldn't be aware of it and services shouldn't be aware of the data layer. Application layer (all application specific code, i.e. UWP or WPF, such as navigation or popup services) can be aware of it. Domain/Business layer is the only know which shouldn't be aware of any other layer

Comment: @Tseng so you are recommending I keep DbContext in the Data layer. You also saying it isn't a problem that my application references the Data layer to be aware of it. The main rule to follow is that Domain doesn't reference anything. It also seems like you are suggesting that I do not create a Services project and just put all of my business logic inside the Domain project. If I do this what is a good naming convention to use for these Business Logic Classes. I usually would do CustomerService or CustomerManager..

Comment: @BlakeRivell: Goes bit far out of scope but there are 2 "schools" on working with domains: anemic domain ,model (no logic and all logic in services) and rich domain model (as much logic as possible in the domain entities such as `Customer` and only a thin service layer for logic that do not fit in there). But its a big topic, you can cover whole books (plural) with it. Use Google. Services: Depends. There are domain and application services,this determine where they get implemented. i.e. navigation service is tightly coupled to a UI (little to no business logic),so it goes to application layer